# How to perform statistical analysis in ggplot2 for groups given 2 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to perform statistical analysis with a dataset as follows

I have two different values for the columns "viroid" (PSTVd & TPMVd) and "expression" (Up-regulated & Down-regulated)

[image]

My code is:

```
ggplot(Both_DEGs, aes(x=Viroid, y=Log2FC, fill=Expression)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme(axis.text.x=NULL)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.format", 
                     label.x = 1.32, label.y = 18, method = "t.test", paired = F)+
  ggtitle("Expression ranges")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, face = "bold"))
```

With this code I obtain this boxplot:

[image]

I would like to perform an statistical analysis grouping my data in four groups given variables "expression" and "viroid". My comparisons would be:

- PSTVd - Up-regulated vs TPMVd - Up-regulated
- PSTVd - Down-regulated vs TPMVd - Down-regulated

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).  And what statistical analysis would you like to perform?  There are many possible.

Comment: Hi! Sorry about that, I am very new in this community. I would like to perform a t-test.

Comment: `ggplot` is for drawing plots. I wouldn't suggest using it for statistical analysis. You can use the `t.test()` function directly without involving `ggplot`.

Comment: (And if you just need help doing t tests, I'd recommend looking at the `?t.test` help page and googling "how to do a t.test in R" - there's plenty of resources out there.)